# Programmatically create a UISearchBar that can be used from multiple views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to create a single UISearchBar that can be viewed and used from multiple views in my app.

For this reason, I have declared a UISearchBar property in my AppDelegate class and initialise it in my very first UIViewController.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

my first view .h

```
@interface MainTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>{

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    NSArray *searchResults;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *accountPage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *search;
```

my first view .m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        self.search = [self.search initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(showSearchBar:)];


    }

        - (IBAction)showSearchBar:(id)sender{

            UIBarButtonItem *searchItem = (UIBarButtonItem *) sender;

            if (searchItem.tag == 0) {
                if (!appDelegate.searchBar) {
                    appDelegate.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
                    [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:appDelegate.searchBar contentsController:self];
                    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
                    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
                    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
                    [self.view addSubview:appDelegate.searchBar];
                } else{
                    [appDelegate.searchBar setHidden:NO];
                }
                searchItem.tag = 1;
            } else{
                searchItem.tag = 0;
                [appDelegate.searchBar setHidden:YES];
            }
        }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } 
    // Set up the cell
    return cell;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSLog(@"filterContentForSearchText");
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"(name contains[cd] %@)",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [appDelegate.elements filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

- (BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{

    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[appDelegate.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[appDelegate.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

However, while the search bar initialised and displayed fine on the VC the search mechanism is not working. I am able to write in search text box but no action. Even 'Search' button from keyboard is not working.

Comment: Where are you implementing the searchBarDelegate methods?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Search Bar and Search Display Controller object in XIB. Simply drag and drop this object in the XIB

and implement table view delegate and data source method.

Like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(tableView == self.aTableView)
    return [self.categories count];//normal table view
    return [self.searchCategories count];//search display controllers TableView
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"reusableCells";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    NSString *text = nil;
    if(tableView == self.aTableView)
        text = [self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else
       text = [self.searchCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = text;

    return cell;
}
```

Search Display controller Methods

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{
    if(self.searchCategories == nil){
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.searchCategories = arr;
        [arr release];
    }else{
        [self.searchCategories removeAllObjects];
    }

    for (NSString *aStr in self.categories) {
        if([[aStr lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchString lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound){
           [self.searchCategories addObject:aStr];
        }
    }
    [controller.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    return NO;
}



- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    [self.aTableView setHidden:YES];
}
- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    [self.aTableView setHidden:NO];
}
```

Hope This will help you. if still you have any problem i recommend you to read details of

```
UISearchDisplayController
```

Comment: Thank you. However, if I would like to have search bar on every VC, I have to do it for every view? There is any way to create a 'global' search bar?

Comment: Yes you have do it for each view controller Other wise you can make your own custom search bar but i will recommend this Search Display controller because it is easy to add(just drag and drop to the xib and implement three mothod) and really looks cool and really easy to use.

Comment: Do you know how I can modify search bar's position? I would like to have a simple animation to show/hide the search bar. Initially, search bar located behind Navigation Bar. Animation works fine but when I am attempting to search, `searchResultsTableView` appears and Navigation Bar alongside with search bar go up, out of screen. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: You should put the search result display object after the navigation bar. select the desired xib-> select the view -> select attributes inspector->selct Top Bar attribute and put a navigation bar. Thats all. You will get cool animation by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `UISearchBarDelegate` methods in respective controller class according to the way you are going to use it.

Refer to this

[Documentation UISearchBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Extending the answer:

In your "my first view .m" file you need to implement UISearchBarDelegate methods inorder to get your actions.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{   
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    //This is where your search button action fires. You can implement what you want to do after search button click in here.   
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
   //This fires whenever you change text in your search bar. For an example if you want to show search suggestions when a new letter is typed you can implement that in here.
}
```

You can use other delegate methods according to your requirement.

Comment: Could you please use some examples, as is my very first time that I am using search bar

Comment: Ok i will improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you. However, still no action!
Using `NSLog` in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` and `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` but they don't printed out. I have `searchResultsDelegate` and `searchResultsDataSource` to self as you can see. Am I doing something wrong `searchBar` while I am trying to use a UISearchBar object that belongs to another class?

Comment: of course you will have to assign it to a property declared in your view controller. If you want you can alloc it within app delegate and assign it to a property defined in your current view controller. but try like this appDelegate.searchBar.delegat =  self; try like this in your view controller after you alloc it, this might work.